# I forgot my 7z password

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-cracking

I used 7zip to encrypt a 200mb archive of my code used a combination of some of 7 possible words and no numbers or caps. So  823543 possible passwords. What is the best free program I can use to recover my password that allows me customize the words it uses.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by '7 possible words'.  Do you mean that your password is 7 `lowercase alphabetical characters` in length?  If so, then that's 8,031,810,176 possible combinations (26^7 = 8031810176).

Comment: @mti2935 There are seven words I use in passwords for achieves. essentially if the program allows substitution of words for letters it is like 7 letters being the whole alphabet.

Comment: I'd like to point out that using passwords that are a permutation of 7 words is risky.

Comment: @neilsmithline I know this is only for this password

Answer (score 1):

I assume I have an answer.

You need to perform a dictionary attack.. ***Kind of..***

The problem is you generally need a hash. If you have one, but I doubt it, then I will give you the answer in an instance. But I doubt you have that in your case. You might need a program specialized for 7zip like  **7zCracker**.

Again, a standard Dictionary Attack software might not help you in your specific task, but in the end that's what 7zCracker will do, it will just check for success in a different way.

*I am no pro, so I apologize  for any mistakes or inconsistencies. Give it a shot with 7zCracker and tell us how it went.*

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple perl script that goes through the possibilities, unzips each one, and looks for a threshold number of dictionary words (or whatever you know to be in the archive) as a verification.